# Mongorestore from stdin

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongodump, mongorestore

**Has someone ever managed to restore a mongodump from stdin?**

I generated the backup file using the referenced command:

```
mongodump --archive > file
```

But the reference never explains in what format the archive is, or how to restore it. Some people say you have to inject it from stdin, but they remains a mystery as *there is no evidence that it is actually possible*.

As a matter of fact, I did the following tries, without any success:

```
cat file | mongorestore
mongorestore -vvvvv --archive < file
mongorestore -vvvvv --archive=file
```

All these commands end up with the same error:

```
Failed: stream or file does not appear to be a mongodump archive
```

For information, I managed to restore an archive that was generated the classic way.

**Why do I need to use the --archive to stdout?**

My mongodb is inside a docker.

The option I'm using now creates the backup file *inside* the docker, that I *then copy to the host*, using the docker cp command, so I *use twice the space* needed (before it's removed inside the container).

Unfortunately, the docker has no mount from the host, and I cannot (yet) restart it to add the option. I was looking for a quick option.

Answer (score 9):

So according to MongoDB official mongodump [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-archive) and mongorestore [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-mongorestore-archive):

> To output the dump to the standard output stream in order to pipe to another process, run mongodump with the archive option but omit the filename.
>   To restore from the standard input, run mongorestore with the --archive option but omit the filename.

So actually you don't have to mongodump to file first and then read from it, just simply pipe mongodump and mongorestore like this:

```
mongodump --archive | mongorestore --archive --drop
```

However, you may probably get another problem as I did https://stackoverflow.com/a/56550768/3785901.

In my case, I have to use --nsFrom and --nsTo instead of --db, or the mongorestore didn't work as expected. So the final command I successfully execute to mongodump/mongorestore is:

```
mongodump --host HOST:PORT --db SOURCE_DB --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD --archive | mongorestore --host HOST:PORT --nsFrom 'SOURCE_DB.*' --nsTo 'TARGET_DB.*' --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD  --archive --drop
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Docker version

```bash
# via archive
docker run --rm -i mongo mongodump --uri mongodb://192.168.0.1:27017/test --archive > dump.archive
docker run --rm -i mongo mongorestore --uri mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test --archive --drop < dump.archive

# direct pipe
docker run --rm -i mongo mongodump --uri mongodb://192.168.0.1:27017/test --archive | docker run --rm -i mongo mongorestore --uri mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test --archive --drop
```